# Fabric Crashlytics api key is null despite startWithApiKey

Tags: ios, crashlytics

On my iOS project, I updated Crashlytics from the version 2.x to the version 3.1.0.

I added a script in the `Build Phases` on xCode:

```
if [ ${MY_VAR} == 1 ]; then
    ./Pods/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run <api key> <build secret>
else
    ./Pods/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run <another api key> <another build secret>
```

Then, in my AppDelegate I added `CrashlyticsKit` to `Fabric`:

```
#if MY_VAR
    [Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"api_key"];
#else
    [Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"another_api_key"];
#endif

[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];

NSLog(@"Crashlytics api key: %@", CrashlyticsKit.apiKey);
```

I tried to print the `apiKey` to be sure that everything work well, but unfortunately, the `apiKey` attribute is null.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to use a POD for Fabric when you can just install the Fabric mini app and then this mini app installs the entire thing for you the right way. That's not the run script Twitter has you run when you do from the Fabric IO Application installer, and that's not the way you use your API key either, you don't need to hard code it, Twitter does it all for you. I'll never understand the appeal of Cocoapods, they are entirely worthless and have hidden black boxes like this when you could have saved hours of time just do it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Fabric here. We looked into this because there are a couple of strange things going on here! First off, the code in your AppDelegate should work, but you don't need both:

```
[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey...];
```

and

```
[Fabric with...];
```

You can remove one of them. `[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey]` is considered legacy but it will still to work.

It looks like you discovered a bug in our Crashlytics header file. In our header the property is `apiKey` but in the code it's `APIKey`. You can access the value by calling `CrashlyticsKit.APIKey` if you want to confirm that your logic is working, but we're going to fix this so that it's `CrashlyticsKit.apiKey`.

Are you using the official CocoaPod that we released?

Comment: Thanks @Alexizamerican I kept `[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey...];` instead of `[Fabric with...];`. Unfortunately, `CrashlyticsKit.APIKey` doesn't compile: `Property 'APIKey' not found on object of type 'Crashlytics *'`. I'm using the official CocoaPod that you released.

Comment: How does Crashlytics get the API key if you use `[Fabric with:]`?

Comment: In particular, what should I do when I have an app that will be resigned by a client, for which we have a separate API key?